# Fetch records from database table for month wise

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to retrieve records from a table based on some conditions

See this is my condition : Query to get sum of amount based on the transaction type month wise

See below is my table:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| Field     | Type        |   
+-----------+-------------+
| tran_id   | int(5)      | 
| cus_name  | varchar(30) | 
| acc_no    | int(10)     | 
| tran_date | date        | 
| amount    | int(6)      | 
| tran_type | varchar(20) | 
| cus_id    | int(5)      | 
+-----------+-------------+
```

Display month values as per below format.

```
+-----------+-------------+
| Month     | Month Name  |   
+-----------+-------------+
| 01        | January     | 
| 02        | February    | 
+-----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need .

```
select sum(amount) Sum,tran_type,MONTH(tran_date) Month,MONTHNAME(tran_date) Month Name from your_table group by tran_type,MONTH(tran_date);`
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`monthname`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname) function to extract the name of the month from a `date` field. E.g.:

```
SELECT   tran_type, MONTHNAME(transdate), SUM(amount)
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY tran_type, MONTHNAME(transdate)
```